# Angularjs: Node server that supports html5mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I'm locally developing an Angularjs app. I'm using the same node web server as in the Angularjs [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00). [The link to the code for the web-server on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/scripts/web-server.js).

The problem is that I can't seem to get html5mode to work on the node server. What I understand so far is that i have to add a base href to my app and rewrite the server code. I tried rewriting the node web server code, but I failed and it didn't work. Could someone please help me in what i should exactly change? Or does someone maybe already has a version of the server rewritten?

The link to my app looks like this: `http://localhost:8000/app/index.html`
Also refreshing the page on a html5 link doesn't work. Like this: `http://localhost:8000/schedule`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite incoming requests that aren't to your REST endpoints respond with the same response as the request to /app/index.html.